# Split a string from example of other string collection

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I'd like to build a collection of String (any complex data structure like a collection) that I can use, efficiently, as "example" to know where I can split a given string.
In example I had this String collection:

- abaco code, exchange.
- bold word can be bold.
- tree folder, and tree of leaf.

and a given string:

- omecodeexchangeuthercanbetreeofword

and obtain, from algorithm, something like:

- ome code exchange uther can be tree of word

The part "ome" and "uther" cannot be splitted, so will be left as is (it would be nice if I mark this part like NOT-RECOGNIZED).
I try to analyse KMP algorithm, but are too much far away from my needs, and I'd like to organize collection in a efficient time manner (less than linear to collection size).

I forget to say:

- the split are on string with natural language words mixed with slang words all without spaces
- I already tried a weighted word dictionary based dynamic algorithm, but is too much subjects to errors for equivalent weight on wrong split ("wrong" i mean for natural language)
- I need the best result for this split, using word sequence from string collections as "good example"

Comment: too much complicated question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dynamic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) can be helpful here.

```
f(0) = 0
f(i) = min { f(j) + (dictionary.contains(word.substring(j,i)) ? 0 : i-j)  for each j=0,...,i }
```

The idea is to do an exhaustive search using the above recursive function while trying to minimize the number of letters that do not 'fit'. Using DP techniques, you can avoid repeating calculations and get the correct answer efficiently.

Getting the actual partitions can be done by remembering at each step what `j` was chosen, and retrace your steps from last to first.

**Java code:**

```
    String word = "omecodeexchangeuthercanbetreeofword";
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("abaco", "code", "exchange", "bold", "word", "can", "be", "tree", "folder", "and", "of", "leaf"));
    int n = word.length() + 1;
    int[] f = new int[n];
    int[] jChoices = new int[n];
    f[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int best = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int bestJ = -1;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            int curr = f[j] + (set.contains(word.substring(j, i)) ? 0 : (i-j));
            if (curr < best) {
                best = curr;
                bestJ = j;
            }
        }
        jChoices[i] = bestJ;
        f[i] = best;
    }
    System.out.println("unmatched chars: " + f[n-1]);
    System.out.println("split:");
    int j = n-1;
    List<String> splits = new ArrayList<>();
    while (j > 0) { 
        splits.add(word.substring(jChoices[j],j));
        j = jChoices[j];
    }
    Collections.reverse(splits);
    for (String s : splits) System.out.println(s + " " + (set.contains(s)?"(match)":"(does not match)"));
```

Comment: this is exactly my first try. But there is a lot of comparable weights for different split, so I'd like to improve the result with example of SEQUENCE of words.

Comment: @g.annunziata I don't understand what you mean 'sequence of words'. The algorithm tries to find matches and minimize the total number of "unmatched' characters. That's basically what you describe in your question, is it not what you are after?

Comment: good (java) example, but this algorithm doesn't use "sequentiality" of words from phrase collection for best weight of single choice. In example if found all phrase is better than half phrase or single word.

Comment: @g.annunziata I am really not following you. what's all phrase? what's full phrase? the algorithm tries to find a match to the words with leaving least possible unmatched chars. You can tweak the 'loss function', `(set.contains(word.substring(j, i)) ? 0 : (i-j)` if you had something else in mind.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be done using regular expressions, which are highly optimised for performance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> splitWords = Arrays.asList("abaco", "code", "exchange", "bold", "word", "can", "be", "tree", "folder", "and", "of", "leaf");

    String splitRegex = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < splitWords.size(); i++) {
        if (i > 0)
            splitRegex += "|";
        splitRegex += splitWords.get(i);
    }

    String stringToSplit = "omecodeexchangeuthercanbetreeofword";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(splitRegex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(stringToSplit);

    int previousMatchEnd = 0;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        int matchStart = matcher.start();
        int matchEnd = matcher.end();

        if (matchStart != previousMatchEnd)
            System.out.println("Not recognized: " + stringToSplit.substring(previousMatchEnd, matchStart));

        System.out.println("Match: " + stringToSplit.substring(matchStart, matchEnd));
        previousMatchEnd = matchEnd;
    }

    if (previousMatchEnd != stringToSplit.length())
        System.out.println("Not recognized: " + stringToSplit.substring(previousMatchEnd, stringToSplit.length()));
}
```

Output:

```
Not recognized: ome
Match: code
Match: exchange
Not recognized: uther
Match: can
Match: be
Match: tree
Match: of
Match: word
```

Comment: Regex splits words greedily and is not guaranteed to return the optimal solution.

Comment: Counter example: words={"aa","aaa"}, string="aaab"

Comment: Correct, but it wasn't really clear from the OP question if that is a requirement or not.
If it is, there is no polynomial algorithm to solve the issue, but dynamic programming, as you mention, is probably a good approach.

Comment: DP is polynomial in the length of the input.

Comment: I don't think it's polynomial if there can be multiple matches at some point - you'll have to decide which word to follow. (It is polynomial if the maximum number of splitter words is known beforehand.)

Comment: No, it is polynomial, or to be exact it is `O(n^3)`, assuming searching if a string of length `k` is in a dictionary is `O(k)`. I just added a java code, you can check for your self and try it with large input sizes.

Comment: Apologies, you are correct, I had a somewhat different approach in mind.