# Building Search Engine

Tags: algorithm, search-engine

I had the following interview question in my recent interview. I was able to provide partial answers but I couldn't cover all the edge cases. The question was as follows:

The company has to build a search engine and they have a set of words which can be searched (multiple words can be clubbed together to make a meaningful query).

Now suppose that the list consists of the following words- shoes, adidas, nike, slipper, slippers, nikes, and many more.

Now there's a user who enters 'nikeshoes' (see there's no space in between words) but since the set doesn't have that word, no results are returned. But now, we want to resolve this problem (which is what Google does when we forget to give space in between 2 meaningful words) by providing the user with correct results by modifying the given query into meaningful one to give results for nike shoes. How can this be done?

The solution to this I gave was to employee 'K Gram' (where k=2) technique where I got words as ni, ik, ke, es, sh, ho, oe, es and I use to club these words and then check them with the set if they really were the meaningful words. But then the interviewer asked me a new question of what happens if a new query is entered as 'nikesshoes'. For this, I was unable to provide the answer.

Then I thought of employing Trie Data structure by comparing each word and trying to check if it exists in the trie but it had the same problem as mentioned above.

Another technique that can be employed is Damerau-Levenshtein Technique but it has the same problem.

So can anyone give me the solution to this problem (I am not asking for code but you are welcomed to give the code as well).

Thanks.

Comment: This is called the word-break problem. Here is the best blog post about it: http://thenoisychannel.com/2011/08/08/retiring-a-great-interview-problem/

Comment: In addition to the dupe linked, there is the generalization of the problem, where there could be some characters that don't belong to any word (and we wish to minimize these). I offered a [full java code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23281333/572670) to the generalized problem some time ago.

Comment: @Beginner, were there only two possible strings in the example?

Comment: @amit: won't your algorithm fail when the input is nikesshoes which will convert the word to 'nike sshoes' instead of 'nikes shoes'?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: No, you could have any number of possible strings.

Comment: @Beginner no, because "sshoes" is not in your dictionary of allowed words ;-) But yes, you are right, there might be n possible solutions. So if you're fancy you might want to add a ranking method at the end that ranks based on context.

Comment: In fact there might an exponential number of solutions. Take the string aaaaa..aaaaaa and the dictionary {a, aa, aaa, aaaa, ...}. There are 2^n possible partitions